# How to create a new object using reflection in c#?

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I would like to create a new object that is the instance of the following class.
How to make the object created by relfection equals the instance of the object represented by the class below with reflection c #?

```
public class cPerson
{
    public String name { set; get; }
    public String adress { set; get; }
    public String phone { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: Why with reflection? You'll have to explain what is wrong with `new cPerson()`

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Do you want to use reflection to create an instance of `cPerson`?  Why do you think you need to use reflection?

Comment: Going by your comment below this is the 3rd (1 now deleted) posting of the same vague, underdocuemnted question. Read the comments asking for clarification carefully and respond to them.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're looking for something like [Activator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx):

```
var person = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(cPerson));
```

Of course, you'll probably be using it when the type is unknown at design time, to create object of the same type...

```
var newInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(p.GetType());
```